# Removing the last two columns from this table but keeping the original format?

Tags: tables

Consider:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c, mode=math]*{4}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
                     row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                     row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                     row{odd[3-X]}={belowsep=0.5ex},
                     row{Z}  = {guard}
                    }
        \toprule
    Parameters
        &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    Numerical values
                &       &       &       \\
         \toprule
    a                 & 0.8      &0.8      & 0.8     & 0.8  \\
    aa            & 0.1      & 0.1     & 0.1     & 0.1     \\
    aa      & 0.61    & 0. 68   & 0.52    & 0.79     \\
    a_I        & 0.53    & 0.74    & 0.69    & 0.81     \\
    a             & 0.29    & 0.22     & 0.32   & 0.2     \\
    a            & 0.27    & 0.21     & 0.19   & 0.17     \\
    a              & 0.52    & 0.67      & 0.42   & 0.3     \\
    a        & 0.29    & 0.44      & 0.23   & 0.49     \\
    a  &0.15     & 0.12      & 0.15   & 0.11     \\
    a   &0.21     & 0.14      & 0.19   & 0.13     \\
    a          &0.53     & 0.47      & 0.61   & 0.51     \\
    a        & 0.11    & 0.13      & 0.1     & 0.13     \\
    a    &0.14     & 0.14      & 0.04   & 0.03     \\
    a    &0.16     & 0.16      & 0.07   & 0.02     \\
    a    &0.15     & 0.15      & 0.06   & 0.04     \\
    a    &0.17     & 0.17      & 0.05   & 0.05     \\
    a          &0.2        & 0.2        & 0.27  & 0.24     \\
    a          &0.23      & 0.23       & 0.29  & 0.23     \\
    a          &0.15      & 0.15       & 0.24  & 0.21     \\
    a          &0.14      & 0.14       & 0.22  & 0.22     \\
        \midrule[0.8pt]
        & Figure \textcolor{black}{4.1}       
                & Figure \textcolor{black}{4.2}       
                        & Figure \textcolor{black}{4.3}
                                & Figure \textcolor{black}{4.4} \\
        \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-5}
    \end{tblr}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Parameter values }
        \label{aa}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    
    \begin{document}    
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c, mode=math]*{3}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}]}},
                 row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                 row{odd[3-X]}={belowsep=0.5ex},
                 row{Z}  = {guard}
                }
    \toprule
Parameters
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Numerical values
            &       &             \\
     \toprule
a        & 0.8      &0.8      \\
a              & 0.1      & 0.1       \\
a           & 0.67    & 0. 77    \\
a             & 0.15     & 0.12       \\
a              & 0.12     & 0.11         \\
a         & 0.1      & 0.1     \\
a        & 0.65     & 0.52       \\
a       &0.23     & 0.19         \\
a       &0.6       & 0.6         \\
a        &0.4       & 0.4          \\
a        &0.7       & 0.7        \\
a     &0.2       & 0.2        \\
a     &0.04     & 0.04        \\
a    &0.23      & 0.23        \\
a    &0.19     & 0.19         \\
a           &0.11     & 0.11         \\
a          &0.12     & 0.12       \\

    \midrule[0.8pt]
    & Figure \textcolor{black}{7.1}       
            & Figure \textcolor{black}{7.2} \\      
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-5}
\end{tblr}
\end{center}
\caption{Parameter values . }
    \label{Table7.1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

How do we remove the last two columns while maintaining the format and central headings? My attempt is attached but I feel as if it is slightly off, for example the "Numerical values" isn't centralised.

Comment: @User23456234 I'm sure Zarko will know how to do it as he made the table for me!

Comment: @User23456234 If this is the case, then I will stick with it!

Comment: It's not really a LaTeX problem but an editing problem. If your editor fails to align table separator characters, you need to change editor (or read the documentation). Ditto if it is not able to select and cut a rectangular region. Emacs, TeXStudio can do it and probably many other editors.